# What could be creating syntax errors in my AMPL code?

Tags: equation, ampl

For this ampl code, I keep getting syntax errors when I try to run this mod file. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong, as I have the correct equations written down.

How do I go about fixing this?

var P >= 0;

var Q >= 0;

var R >= 0;

var S >= 0;

var T >= 0;

var U >= 0;

var V >= 0;

maximize Cost:      4*P + 5*Q + 1*R + 3*S - 5*T + 8*U;

subject to Sup1:       P - 4*R + 3*S + T + U + 2*V = 1 ;

subject to Sup2:     5*P + 3*Q + R − 5*T + 3*U    <= 4 ;

subject to Sup3:     4*P + 5*Q − 3*R + 3*S − 4*T + U <= 4 ;

subject to Sup4:         −  Q + 2*S + T − 5*U <= 5 ;

subject to Sup5:    −2*P + Q + R +  S + 2*T + 2*U <= 7 ;

subject to Sup6:     2*P − 3*Q + 2*R - S + 4*T + 5*U <= 5 ;

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is caused by the Unicode minus sign `−`. To fix it replace all occurrences of `−` with the standard ASCII minus sign `-`.